# Why might boto be denied access to S3 with proper IAM keys?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, amazon-iam

I am trying to access a bucket on S3 with boto. I have been given read access to the bucket and my keys are working when I explore it in S3 Browser. The following code is returning 403 Forbidden Access Denied.

```
conn = S3Connection('Access_Key_ID', 'Secret_Access_Key')
conn.get_all_buckets()
```

This also occurs when using the access key and secret access key via the boto config file. Is there something else I need to be doing because the keys are from IAM perhaps? Could this indicate an error in the setup? I don't know much about IAM, I was just given the keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that it's because you're calling `conn.get_all_buckets()` instead of `conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)` for the individual bucket you have access to.

Comment: Same thing occurs when I specify the bucket.

Comment: Turns out you were correct. The one addition being that for IAM keys you also need a trailing '/' on the bucket name.

Answer (score 6):

Some things to check...

- If you are using boto, be sure you are using conn.get_bucket(bucket_name) to access only the bucket you have permission to access.
- In your IAM (user) policy, if you are restricting access to a single 
  bucket, be sure that the policy includes adequate permissions to the 
  bucket and do not include a trailing slash+asterisks for the ARN name (see example below).
- Be sure to set "Upload/Delete" permissions for "Authenticated Users" in S3 for the bucket.

**Permissions sample:**

[image]

**IAM policy sample:**

*NOTE: The SID will be automatically generated when using the policy generator*

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Sid": "Stmt0000000000001",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vyke! Setting "Upload/Delete" permissions for "Authenticated Users" in S3 for the bucket did the trick for me. BTW, I was able to make it work with more restrictive permissions in the IAM user policy: rather than s3:*, only s3:ListBucket, s3:DeleteObject and s3:PutObject were needed for my purposes.

Comment: Are you sure granting access to "Authenticated Users" doesn't let *everyone* access the bucket, and render the IAM policy useless? [The docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html) make it sound like it would.

Comment: Agreed.  Granting access to Any Authenticated AWS User sounds like it grants access to literally any authenticated aws user instead of ones that are authenticated specifically to your account.  Can someone clarify this and present a better solution?

Comment: Granting permission for "Authenticated Users" - IS NOT SECURE !
It lets access to your bucket for everyone (just need any aws account).
You need to spend huge amount of time trying to find working solution for you.
Access validation is so buggy on aws. It consist from 3 parts:
1) IAM role permissions
2) Bucket access policies.
3) ACL - obsolete system - that just ruining whole security and able to compromise your data.

Everything is just multiplying with bugs in APIs like boto.
I really recommend to switch to other system than s3.

Answer (score -2):

`from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection('access key', 'secret access key')
allBuckets = conn.get_all_buckets()
for bucket in allBuckets:
   print(str(bucket.name))`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.